# Get The Procces ID of a service on OnStart of the service

Tags: c#, service

I have a Windows Service that i create.

I need to get the PID of the process when running and save it to DB.

On My OnStart

```
timer1 = new Timer();
double Interval = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["intervalInSeconds"].ToString());
this.timer1.Interval = Interval * 1000;
this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
timer1.Enabled = true;

Library.WriteErrorLog("service started");
```

I Tried to get the PID using

GetService but it dosent work.

Comment: `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id`?

Comment: What is Process In My Code?

Answer (score 0):

You can query if from the Managementobject like list

```
private static uint GetProcessIDByServiceName(string serviceName)
 {
   uint processId = 0;
   string qry = "SELECT PROCESSID FROM WIN32_SERVICE WHERE NAME = '" + serviceName + "'";
   System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(qry);
   foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject mngntObj in searcher.Get())
    {
      processId = (uint)mngntObj["PROCESSID"];
    }
    return processId;
 }
```

Comment: i tried to use it but i always get 0
timer1 = new Timer();
            double Interval = Convert.ToDouble(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["intervalInSeconds"].ToString());
            this.timer1.Interval = Interval * 1000;
            this.timer1.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            uint PID = GetProcessIDByServiceName("MessagingService.exe");
            Library.WriteErrorLog("service started PID=" + PID.ToString());

Comment: But It's running I see it in the process list